# How to backup my qemu windows VR

Tags: backup, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-mate, qemu

I have a Ubuntu mate machine which I use for work and I use a windows VM on qemu for accessing enterprise tools(just a few like resetting my NT password) and all it's working perfect. The question here is:

How or which is the right process to backup my qemy VM if I'm going to install a new Ubuntu in the same computer and presser the same configurations?

Comment: This should work: https://serverfault.com/questions/530848/how-to-properly-back-up-a-live-qemu-kvm-vm

Comment: Solved following the next [steps](https://serverfault.com/questions/434064/correct-way-to-move-kvm-vm)